# HttpPost and HttpGet Not working?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In Mvc application, i created a simple application, HttGet, HttpPost but not working.
This is my code:

Model:

```
public class SasiClass
{
    public int SasiId { get; set; }
    public string SasiName { get; set; }
    public string SasiAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CreateSasi()
    {
        SasiClass objSasi = new SasiClass();
        return View(objSasi);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateSasi(SasiClass obj)
    {
        return View("Show",obj); 

    }
```

View:
   Create Sasi:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateSasi", "Home"))
{
 <table >
   <tr>
      <td>Sasi ID</td>
      <td>@Html.TextBox("SasiId",@Model.SasiId ) </td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Sasi Name</td>
     <td>@Html.TextBox("SasiName",@Model.SasiName) </td>
 </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sasi Address</td>
     <td>@Html.TextBox("SasiAddress",@Model.SasiAddress) </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
       <td colspan="2">@Html.ActionLink("Submit","CreateSasi")  </td>  
  </tr>
 </table>
 }
```

Show:
   View

```
  <table>
 <tr>
  <td>Id: </td>
  <td>@Model.SasiId</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Name: </td>
  <td>@Model.SasiName</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Address: </td>
     <td>@Html.TextBox("address", @Model.SasiAddress)</td>
   </tr>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear: what is not working HttGet or HttpPost? Can you extend your question? You should also add some description on what do you do, what is happening, and what do you expect to happen.

Comment: actually when i click on submit, the page is not redirecting to "Show" [View]

Comment: Is there an error message?  Can you post the Show view code?

Comment: it is not showing error, but it is not redirecting, when i click on Submit link it is stay in the same page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should have SasiId instead of Id in view

```
<td>@Html.TextBox("SasiId",@Model.SasiId ) </td>
```

EDIT!!!

You should submit form, instead you are linking to action! This is false in this case:

```
<td colspan="2">@Html.ActionLink("Submit","CreateSasi")  </td>
```

Do like this:

```
<td colspan="2"><input type="submit"/>  </td>
```